# Python: Standardised matrix

Tags: python, python-3.x

data = [[1, 2, 3, 4], [2, 6, 7, 7], [3, 6, 2, 9], [4, 7, 4, 3]]

I want to standardise a matrix(list of lists) and I have a mean and standard deviation function already. The standardised matrix function is only allowed to take one parameter which is the list of lists

```
def get_mean(matrix, column):
    x = [item[col] for item in mat]
    return statistics.mean(x)

def get_std(matrix, column):
    x = [item[col] for item in mat]
    return statistics.stdev(x)
```

(, ) = ((, ) − mean((: , ))) /  ((: , ))

where matrix(x,y) is my list of lists. x is the row number and y is the column number.

mean(matrix(:,y)) is the mean of column y over all the rows, and
std(matrix(:,y)) is the standard deviation of column y over all the rows.

This is what I tried but it returns the standardised matrix 4 times over

```
get_standardised_matrix(matrix):
    alist = []
    for y in range(len(matrix)):
        alist.append([[((z - get_mean(matrix, y)) / get_sd(matrix, y)) for z in x] for x in matrix])
    return alist
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes that's what it does, all right.  Look at your control logic: a double-iteration list comprehension that steps through the *entire* matrix, wrapped in another loop that iterates through each column.  This gives you 4x4x4 iterations.

You need to remove the innermost iteration of the comprehension.